NavigationStackView DetailView not reseting States and StateObjects when changing selection
I have a 3 column NavigationSplitView where a detailView takes a flight which is a Core Data model like so.
import SwiftUI

enum SideBarMenuCategory: Int, CaseIterable, Identifiable {
    case flights
    var id: Int { rawValue }
}

class FlightModel: ObservableObject {
    let id: UUID
    let text: String

    init(text: String) {
        self.id = UUID()
        self.text = text
    }
}

class RouteManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selectedCategory: SideBarMenuCategory? = .flights
    @Published var visibility: NavigationSplitViewVisibility = .automatic
    @Published var selectedFlight: FlightModel? = nil

    @Published var selectedFlights = Set<UUID>() {
        didSet {
            updateSelectedFlight()
        }
    }

    let flightStore = FlightStore.instance

    func updateSelectedFlight() {
        guard selectedFlights.count == 1,
              let flightID = selectedFlights.first
        else {
            selectedFlight = nil
            return
        }
        selectedFlight = flightStore.findFlight(by: flightID)
    }
}

class FlightStore: ObservableObject {
    static let instance = FlightStore()

    private init() {}

    @Published var flights: [FlightModel] = [FlightModel(text: "Test"), FlightModel(text: "Test 2")]

    func findFlight(by id: UUID?) -> FlightModel? {
        flights.first { $0.id == id }
    }
}

struct SidebarView: View {
    @Binding var selectedCategory: SideBarMenuCategory?

    var body: some View {
        List(selection: $selectedCategory) {
            NavigationLink(value: SideBarMenuCategory.flights) {
                Label("Flights", systemImage: "book")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct FlightsOverView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var routeManager: RouteManager
    @EnvironmentObject var flightStore: FlightStore

    var body: some View {
        List(flightStore.flights, id: \.id, selection: $routeManager.selectedFlights) { flight in
            HStack {
                Text(flight.id.uuidString)
                Spacer()
                Text(flight.text)
            }
            .tag(flight.id)
        }
    }
}

struct SplitView: View {
    @StateObject var routeManager = RouteManager()
    @StateObject var flightStore = FlightStore.instance

    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView(columnVisibility: $routeManager.visibility) {
            SidebarView(selectedCategory: $routeManager.selectedCategory)
                .navigationTitle("Menu")
        } content: {
            SecondColumnView()
        } detail: {
            ThirdColumnView()
        }
        .environmentObject(routeManager)
        .environmentObject(flightStore)
    }
}

struct SecondColumnView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var routeManager: RouteManager

    var body: some View {
        if let selectedCategory = routeManager.selectedCategory {
            switch selectedCategory {
            case .flights:
                FlightsOverView()
            }
        } else {
            EmptyView()
        }
    }
}

struct ThirdColumnView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var routeManager: RouteManager

    var body: some View {
        if let category = routeManager.selectedCategory {
            switch category {
            case .flights:
                if let flight = routeManager.selectedFlight {
                    FlightDetailView(flight: flight)
                }
            }
        } else {
            Text("Select View")
        }
    }
}

class DetailVM: ObservableObject {
    init() {
        print("DetailVM is Init")
    }

    deinit {
        print("DetailVM is Deinit")
    }
}

struct FlightDetailView: View {
    @ObservedObject var flight: FlightModel
    @StateObject var detailVM = DetailVM()

    @State var isOn = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            Text(flight.text)
            Toggle("", isOn: $isOn)
        }
        .task {
            print("I want to set something up")
        }
        .onDisappear {
            print("I want to perform some checks")
        }
    }
}


FlightsOverView holds List with selection. That selection returns a Set<UUID> which I filter and return a selectedFlight. The change takes place as expected and view updates. However, all @StateObject and @State held by FlightDetailView do not reset when changing selection (.task runs exactly once on the initial selection and .onDisappear is never invoked). I am migrating from NavigationStack where this isn't an issue as the view disappears before another one can be selected. How could this be fixed in NavigationSplitView?
I tried assigning a .id(flight.id) to the view but this only causes in @StateObjects of that view to init each time flight selection is changed but no deinit takes place.
EDIT: Added minimal reproducible code
2nd EDIT: After quite some digging I have found a culprit - Menu in the toolBar of the detail view. The Menu in the toolbar is for some reason causing to hold all @StateObjects for that view even if the user navigates to a different view.
struct FlightDetailView: View {
    @ObservedObject var flight: FlightModel
    @StateObject var detailVM = DetailVM()

    @State var isOn = false

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            VStack(alignment: .center) {
                Text(selectedFlight?.text ?? "no selectedFlight").foregroundStyle(.blue)
                Toggle("", isOn: $isOn)
            }
        }
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarTrailing){
// without this Menu, the StateObjects are deinit when navigating away
                Menu {
                    Button("Flight") {
                        selectedFlight?.text = "Is Flying Now"
                    }
                }label: {
                    Label("Test", systemImage: "book.fill")
                }
                
                
            }
        }
        .task {
            print("I want to set something up")
        }
        .onDisappear {
            print("I want to perform some checks")
        }
    }
}

This wasn't in the original post, since I didn't suspect the code in detail view to have anything to do with this, but rather my data flow structure.

its a bad idea to centralise navigation in a router object its best to use the View struct hierarchy to your advantage to decentralise all the navigation modifiers. StateObject is only when you need a reference type in a State, i.e. doing something with Combine or delegates.

Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: minimal code. A minimum code that we can compile and run that replicates your issues. What’s FlightsOverView?
And what does this mean ...all @StateObject and @State held by FlightDetailView do not reset when changing selection
and how many @StateObject do you declare, and how do you pass them to your SplitView.

Hi guys! I have just updated the code to provide minimal reproducible code. Maybe it will be now more clear. I put in dummy prints in the detail view to show what I  mean. In the real code I have some @State vars which I sync on appear with the core data model (Pickers) and need to update them when navigating from one view to another. You can see on the @State var isOn = false that the selection is carried over from one view to another. I am new to the NavigationSplitView so I am wondering if this my bug or if this is feature...

Have a look at this Apple link  Monitoring data for how to manage data in your app.
In essence, don’t nest ObservableObjects and don’t use them if you are not using @Published, eg
your FlightModel and DetailVM. It is not a good idea to have a  ObservableObject a singleton.
I recommend you restructure your code, where you have all the data manipulation/fetching etc... in one source of truth ObservableObject ,
and let the Views do the user interface, do the selections and navigation.

Thanks a lot for your inputs! I will definitely have to have a look at the data structure I have, but it is already quite a large project so it will take some time to refactor. In the meantime I found a culprit in Menu which is causing all the views to hold onto the StateObjects (I have edited the original post to add the code)

You could try this approach, where you have all the data manipulation/fetching etc... in one source of truth class FlightStore: ObservableObject,
and let the Views do the user interface, the selections and the navigation
using @State variables, as shown in the example code:
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        SplitView()
    }
}

enum SideBarMenuCategory: Int, CaseIterable, Identifiable {
    case flights
    var id: Int { rawValue }
}

struct FlightModel: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    var isFlying: Bool = false
    var text: String
}

class FlightStore: ObservableObject {
    @Published var flights: [FlightModel] = [FlightModel(text: "Test 1"), FlightModel(text: "Test 2")]
}

struct SidebarView: View {
    @Binding var selectedCategory: SideBarMenuCategory?

    var body: some View {
        List(selection: $selectedCategory) {
            NavigationLink(value: SideBarMenuCategory.flights) {
                Label("Flights", systemImage: "book")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SplitView: View {
    @StateObject private var flightStore = FlightStore()
    
    @State private var visibility: NavigationSplitViewVisibility = .automatic
    
    @State private var selectedCategory: SideBarMenuCategory? = .flights
    @State private var selectedFlight: FlightModel?

    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView(columnVisibility: $visibility) {
            SidebarView(selectedCategory: $selectedCategory)
                .navigationTitle("Menu")
        } content: {
            SecondColumnView(selectedCategory: $selectedCategory, selectedFlight: $selectedFlight)
        } detail: {
            ThirdColumnView(selectedCategory: $selectedCategory, selectedFlight: $selectedFlight)
        }
        .environmentObject(flightStore)
        .onAppear {
            selectedFlight = flightStore.flights.first
        }
    }
}

struct SecondColumnView: View {
    @Binding var selectedCategory: SideBarMenuCategory?
    @Binding var selectedFlight: FlightModel?

    var body: some View {
        if let selectedCategory = selectedCategory {
            switch selectedCategory {
            case .flights:
                FlightsOverView(selectedFlight: $selectedFlight)
            }
        } else {
            Text("in SecondColumnView")
        }
    }
}

struct FlightsOverView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var flightStore: FlightStore
    @Binding var selectedFlight: FlightModel?

    var body: some View {
        List(flightStore.flights, selection: $selectedFlight) { flight in
            HStack {
                Text(flight.id.uuidString)
                Spacer()
                Text(flight.text)
                Text(flight.isFlying ? " flying" : " on ground").foregroundStyle(.red)
                Spacer()
            }.tag(flight)
        }
    }
}

struct ThirdColumnView: View {
    @Binding var selectedCategory: SideBarMenuCategory?
    @Binding var selectedFlight: FlightModel?

    var body: some View {
        if let category = selectedCategory {
            switch category {
            case .flights:
                FlightDetailView(selectedFlight: $selectedFlight)
                    .id(selectedFlight?.id)
            }
        } else {
            Text("ThirdColumnView")
        }
    }
}

struct FlightDetailView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var flightStore: FlightStore
    @Binding var selectedFlight: FlightModel?

    @State private var isOn = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            Text(selectedFlight?.text ?? "no selectedFlight").foregroundStyle(.blue)
            Toggle("", isOn: $isOn)
        }
        .onAppear {
            isOn = selectedFlight?.isFlying ?? false
        }
        .onChange(of: isOn) {
            selectedFlight?.isFlying = isOn
            if let flight = selectedFlight, let index = flightStore.flights.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == flight.id }) {
                flightStore.flights[index].isFlying = flight.isFlying
            }
        }
        .task {
            print("I want to set something up")
        }
        .onDisappear {
            print("I want to perform some checks")
        }
    }
}

If you are targeting ios-17+, then I recommend you use Observable, see Managing model data in your app
